# Shift pd.dataframe's rows depending of value in a specific cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine we have a dataframe with structure like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Year':[2017, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017],
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[0,0,0,0,0,7],
         'D':[0,1,3,5,7,1],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
```

General idea is to shift each rows, corresponds to value in the 'Year' column, 2017 is the base year, each other row should be shifted to the right on (Year - 2017) cells and new cells should be filled by zeros (0), like :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Year':[2017, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017],
         'B':[4,0,0,5,5,4],
         'C':[0,0,4,0,0,7],
         'D':[0,5,0,5,7,1],
         'E':[5,0,3,9,2,4],
         'F':[0,1,6,0,0,0],
         'G':[0,3,0,0,0,0],
})
```

ps: Actualy we then need to sum pair-wise some of result rows, so that 'Year' of each column are the same

It's only for first step when we sum 0 and 2 rows. Then it should be 1 and 3, and so on

[image]
So, maybe there is some pandas functionality which helps to do this task without pre-shifting...

Comment: _Actualy we then need to sum pair-wise some of result rows, so that 'Year' of each column are the same _ Can you be more specific? What determines which rows should be summed?

Comment: How your final dataframe look lilke ?

Comment: @Alexander Cécile Sorry for confusing you. As a result we have to sum rows 0 and 2, 1 and 3, and so on. We need to shift it because for example cell df.iloc[0,1] relates to 2017 year, but df.iloc[1,1] relates to 2019 year so we cannot sum them.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand. How are you handling the fact that there are years which appear multiple times?

Comment: @Alexander Cécile you mean '2017'? we don't need to change rows which contain '2017' in the 'Year' column.

Comment: Alright, good. Then I don't understand this idea: _cell df.iloc[0,1] relates to 2017 year, but df.iloc[1,1] relates to 2019 year so we cannot sum them_

Comment: @Alexander Cécile it means that we cannot just sum df.iloc[0, 1:] with df.iloc[1, 1:] because first we need to shift second row on 2 cells right, because value df.iloc[0,1] relates to 2017 year but  df.iloc[1,1] relates to 2019 year

Comment: How do we know that, though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204104/discussion-between---and-alexander-cecile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If use `shift` in pandas by default, then last columns are lost. So is necessary first add new columns filled by missing values - number of columns depends of difference of non 2017 values.

```
df = df.set_index('Year')

diff = np.setdiff1d(df.index.dropna().unique(), [2017]).astype(int)
print (diff)
[2018 2019]

df = df.assign(**{f'new{x}':np.nan for x in range(max(diff-2017))})
```

Then you can use `shift` in loop and filter by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) by years in index:

```
for y in diff:
    df.loc[y, :] = df.astype(float).shift(y - 2017, axis=1).loc[y, :]
```

Last replace missing values, cast to integers and convert index to columns:

```
df = df.fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
   Year  B  C  D  E  new0  new1
0  2017  4  0  0  5     0     0
1  2019  0  0  5  0     1     3
2  2018  0  4  0  3     6     0
3  2017  5  0  5  9     0     0
4  2017  5  0  7  2     0     0
5  2017  4  7  1  4     0     0
```

EDIT:

Solution with another column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'new':list('abcdef'),
         'Year':[2017, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017],
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[0,0,0,0,0,7],
         'D':[0,1,3,5,7,1],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})
print (df)
  new  Year  B  C  D  E
0   a  2017  4  0  0  5
1   b  2019  5  0  1  3
2   c  2018  4  0  3  6
3   d  2017  5  0  5  9
4   e  2017  5  0  7  2
5   f  2017  4  7  1  4
```

---

```
df = df.set_index(['new','Year'])

diff = np.setdiff1d(df.index.get_level_values('Year').dropna().unique(), [2017]).astype(int)
print (diff)
[2018 2019]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=['new{}'.format(x) for x in range(max(diff-2017))])
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1) 
print (df)
          B  C  D  E new0 new1
new Year                      
a   2017  4  0  0  5  NaN  NaN
b   2019  5  0  1  3  NaN  NaN
c   2018  4  0  3  6  NaN  NaN
d   2017  5  0  5  9  NaN  NaN
e   2017  5  0  7  2  NaN  NaN
f   2017  4  7  1  4  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
for y in diff:
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    df.loc[idx[:, y], :] = df.astype(float).shift(y - 2017, axis=1).loc[idx[:, y], :]

df = df.fillna(0).astype(int).reset_index()
print (df)
  new  Year  B  C  D  E  new0  new1
0   a  2017  4  0  0  5     0     0
1   b  2019  0  0  5  0     1     3
2   c  2018  0  4  0  3     6     0
3   d  2017  5  0  5  9     0     0
4   e  2017  5  0  7  2     0     0
5   f  2017  4  7  1  4     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

I created programmatically the steps you took from the first df frame to the last one. I did this because it seems like you may be looking for how to do that programmatically, and it may help with your end result. With a little more understanding, i can probably make this process easier:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Year':[2017, 2019, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2017],
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[0,0,0,0,0,7],
         'D':[0,1,3,5,7,1],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],})

df.insert(column='F',loc=len(df)-1,value=np.zeros(len(df),dtype=int)) 
df.insert(column='G',loc=len(df)-1,value=np.zeros(len(df),dtype=int)) 
df1 = df.T
cols =df1.iloc[0]
df1.columns = cols
df1.drop('Year', inplace=True)
df1.iloc[0:, [1]] =  np.roll(df1.iloc[0:, [1]], shift=2)
df1.iloc[0:, [2]] =  np.roll(df1.iloc[0:, [2]], shift=1)

df = df1.T.reset_index() 
res = df.iloc[2] + df.iloc[0]
df = df.append(res, ignore_index=True)
df['Year'][6]= 'res'
```

output:

```
   Year  B  C  D  E  G  F
0  2017  4  0  0  5  0  0
1  2019  0  0  5  0  1  3
2  2018  0  4  0  3  6  0
3  2017  5  0  5  9  0  0
4  2017  5  0  7  2  0  0
5  2017  4  7  1  4  0  0
6   res  4  4  0  8  6  0
```

Comment: `Actualy in a full df 'Year' is in range [2017, 2035]` in chat